# Need for an application Server - Java

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, architecture, jboss, glassfish

I come from a client side programming background (C++ mostly). However, I now have the occasional need to get into some small server side projects in Java & hence need some advice from experienced server side people. I don't really understand much about Application servers.

Are there any thumb rules or considerations to decide when a program needs an application server (like GlassFish or JBoss)?

I have 2 servers written in Java both running on dedicated machines. One server runs on Tomcat without any App Server. The second server runs on an application server(Glassfish).

I need to write a rather simple program which sits in the middle. This is what the program will do

- listen on a socket. When a connection comes from the first server, it creates a thread to accept the connection & continue listening.
- the thread gets a small amount of data (say 100-200 bytes) from the first server, does very minor formatting of the data & passes it on to the second server through a webservice call. It takes return value of the webservice call, and based on it does some processing - may be around 10-20 lines of code - this is not some major processing - just a few  webservice calls on a different (3rd) server. After this, it returns some data back to the first server - again not much - may be 50 bytes.
- My program is not a webservice. It just gets messages from the first server in a particular format & makes a webservice call to the 2nd server based on the data received from the first server. In someways you can think of it in this way - it acts as a proxy for the first server to make a webservice call into the 2nd server.

All the major work is done by the first server running by the app running on the Tomcat Server & the Web Services running on GlassFish. These both are well tested programs. The middle program I want to write is pretty simple & I can get it done in half day. However, what I am worried about is if it will be able to take the load.

What kind of rules/considerations are there to figure out if I can just run this Java program as a regular windows service or do I need something like Glassfish or any other Application Server.

Should I consider the number of connections coming in per minute/hour? I will be forking a thread for each connection but the thread itself would not be very long lived. At what threshold of number of connections should I consider an Application Server? Are there any other considerations? I would highly prefer to avoid an Application Server, if possible.

Whether to run it under an App Server is just one question - are there any more questions I am missing here?

Comment: Not sure if this fits in your use case, but one standard way of such service connectivity is through a pub-sub model using JMS queues. Every service has a message queue. You get messages piled up in your queue, process them and post results to some other service's queue.

Comment: @Singularity - the 1st server sends it's message in a particular format and expects a reply in a particular format. I will look into JMS Queues, but I assume JMS queues have their own format.

Comment: Yes JMS uses XML(Soap), but CDATA tags allow to put any raw data in XML.

Comment: @Singularity - can't change either of servers (i.e. the format they send and receive messages in) - so JMS doesn't seem to be suitable for me

Comment: Then I think, you should go with the methods posted in answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Application servers are not magical, in that they do not create better performance.  In fact, for a simple application such as you've outlined, an application server would likely have the opposite effect because of all the extra overhead most application servers introduce.

Application servers provide infrastructure components, pragmatic patterns for enterprise level development, and implementations of standards specifications.  They are primarily useful for organizing larger scale development efforts and setting things up to scale for larger numbers of relatively short-lived connections.  That said, light weight servers such as Tomcat or Jetty can be used if you are already familiar with the infrastructure that they provide.  In particular, they would provide inbound HTTP connection handling for you.

I think based on your problem description though, you would be better off writing a standalone java service using libraries like [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) to handle the HTTP and WebService client functionality.   It's not clear how much extra work you need to handle inbound connections. If simple sockets, then it's very easy to program this yourself.

Your description regarding how many connections you will need to support simultaneously is vague (and it's all relative).  If you need one thread per connection and expect to support hundreds of connections, then I would suggest implementing your connection handling with a thread connection pool, making sure that new connections block before exhausting your server's capabilities.  If going that route, check out the Java 5+ [ExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) and related classes.

I doubt an Application server will provide much benefit if your needs are simple.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Few clarifications - am using Axis to make the webservice calls. And it serves all the needs I have. Also I need 1 thread per connection - will look into ExecutorService. When you ask about  `need to support hundreds of connections` - I assume you are talking about concurrent, right?

Comment: Regarding load, it really depends on your scenario. If threads are primarily blocking while waiting for IO response, then 100s of concurrent connections is easily achievable. If your threads are always active, then 100s of _active_ threads will likely require serious hardware.  But if your threads are short-lived and it's okay for new conns to wait a short period, then you could have a pool of a max 50 threads, yet have queue of 1000s of connections ready to be serviced. The definition of "concurrent connections" can be tricky.

Answer (score 1):

The basic rule when assessing any tool should also apply here: will it make my work easier.

So the question is: are the feature provided by the application server usfull for my use case and limitation won't border me.

Base on the description of your user case:

The `JavaEE` application server will provide Servlet abstraction to easily manage `HTTP` request (in theory other type of request can be implement by you will need to do it your self by adding new stuff to the implementation of the app server).  It will also provide via `Jax-WS` or `Jax-RS` abstraction to web service endpoint creation.

The cost of these abstraction is that the applicaiton server will manage the threading,.  Most of the implementation will use thread pool for `HTTP` connections, so no cost of thread creation on each request.

In addition full `JavaEE` will provide you easy declarative transaction and security (`EJB`), peristant messaging with `JMS` and others.

It up to you to balance the added value of the provided abstraction and the cost of them (less control, in most case less control will result in better behaviour as Java standards have been made to match most use case and then performe better than average programmer code...).

So in you case you should review the functionality you requirer, use the most easy way (quickets) to meet your functionality and made a POC to make some load test.

By the way Tomcat **is** an application server, it only doesn't implement all the JavaEE part, it only implements the basique web related feature (servlet, but by default no WS or restfull ws but this can be easily added by libs).  The new Jboss and Glassfich provide much more functionlaity (leasy loaded at deployment) with similar size and performance than Tomcat.

Comment: My program is not a webservice. It's just listens on a socket. It expects messages in a particular format (not SOAP or anything) & forwards to a webservice by making the webservice call. I also does some processing along the way.

Answer (score 1):

I think the performance concerns will be impacted more by your network topology and machine hardware than by your choice of application server. Some application servers, like JBoss, offer management tools for creating and managing clusters but all application servers can be set up similarly with the right tools. That said, I think you would be well served with a an embeddable servlet container like [jetty](http://jetty.codehaus.org/jetty/) or [grizzly](http://grizzly.java.net/). This will give you the configuration and portability benefits conveyed by an application server without the extra baggage of EE compliance you are unlikely to need and will make it easy to set up your development configuration.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `configuration and portability` benefits. Also how much effort would be need to take a simple program like I described & modify it to run under `jetty` or `grizzly`.

Comment: A good example of configuration is being able to manage the threadpool settings via the Jetty xml file, example here: http://docs.codehaus.org/display/JETTY/Newbie+Guide+to+Jetty#NewbieGuidetoJetty-ThreadPooloptional

Comment: In terms of modifying an existing app to work with it, check on the documentation on embedding Jetty, I think you will find that creating a  class to start the server and add a context is very straightforward: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty